# Should I use preposition TO?

Tags: prepositions

To situate a geographical area relatively to another, should one use preposition TO or no preposition at all in these examples:
"TO the east of the USA, there is the Atlantic Ocean." or "The state of Alaska is TO the northwest of Canada."
or "East of the USA, there is the Atlantic Ocean." or "The state of Alaska is northwest of Canada."
Does the use of TO depend on the order of the sentence?

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+south+of%2Cis+to+the+south+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20south%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20to%20the%20south%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cis%20south%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20to%20the%20south%20of%3B%2Cc0) showing that a couple of centuries ago, a place was actually *more* likely to be described as ***to the** south of [some other place to its north]*. But that's very much a minority usage today, when most of us just say *The state of Alaska is northwest of Canada* (no ***to the***).

Comment: The Atlantic Ocean is on the eastern seaboard of the US. None of those to's work.

Comment: to can be very literary: to the north, lay the vast expanse of the Arctic.

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't matter.  A native English speaker might say it either way, either with or without the "to the."

However, I would drop the "there" in the Atlantic Ocean example.  It would be better to say "East of the USA is the Atlantic Ocean" or "to the East of the USA is the Atlantic Ocean."

Answer (score 0):

Be concerned about when to.use capitalization and "the."
I. can imagine a tour guide giving a preview or overview of an excursion, pointing to a map saying #1, which uses "there."

Comment: Under what circumstances could you justify "East," not "east" in sentence #6 by JasonR?